# Filter array of tuple with an array of Double SCALA

Tags: scala, list, filter

I am very new to scala. Here is my issue:

I have an array:

```
val numbers = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

And an array of tupples.

```
val arrayTuple= Array((1,2),(10,5),(40,5),(3,4))
```

I would like to filter this list and keep only tuples that have their first elment in the list numbers.

```
val filtered=arrayTuple.filter(numbers.contains(_.1)).map(x=>x)
```

But it doesn't work. Can you help me please. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax to access the first element of a tuple is wrong (see the [Scaladoc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Tuple2.html)). You also don't need the map:

```
val filtered = arrayTuple.filter(t => numbers.contains(t._1))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!